# strange routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1

Here is my routes.rb

```
resources :ads
```

I thought this entry was supposed to cover pretty much anything that will be placed under /ads URL and have a corresponding method in controller. The strange thing it works for everything under /ads, but when I try to get to ads/:id/delete I receive an error:
    No route matches [GET] "/ads/50/delete"

If I add explicit entry

```
match 'ads/:id/delete' => 'ads#delete'
```

then everything works

entry from controller

```
 def delete
      @ad=Ad.find(params[:id])
      @ad.destroy
      redirect_to '/ads'
  end
```

a) I'm trying to figure put why the entry resources :ads doesn't work for /ads/:id/delete
b) any pointers as to a simple way to debug routing issues would be appreciated.

UPD:
Output for the rake routes

```
c:\RailsInstaller\work\mebay>rake routes
    ads GET    /ads(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"ads"}
        POST   /ads(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"ads"}
 new_ad GET    /ads/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"ads"}
edit_ad GET    /ads/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"ads"}
     ad GET    /ads/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"ads"}
        PUT    /ads/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"ads"}
        DELETE /ads/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"ads"}
               /ads/:id/delete(.:format) {:controller=>"ads", :action=>"delete"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The routes that are generated are "RESTful" -- so while you do get access to create, update, delete, etc. your records, you have to make sure you're using the proper REST verb. In your case, it looks like you're trying to send a GET request to your delete path, which won't work. You need to send a DELETE request instead.

If you post your actual code for the link that's used to delete this we can give you a more specific answer, but generally your delete link should look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", ad_path(@ad), :method => :delete %>
```

This will send a DELETE request to /ads/:id, which Rails will know should call your `destroy` action.

The official Ruby on Rails Routing guide in @Tilo's answer is a **great** resource that you should read through before moving forward.

Comment: "it looks like you're trying to send a GET request to your delete path, which won't work."   _________________ I'm not really good with those things, but it looks like that this is what's happening. When I enable explicit routing (match 'ads/:id/delete' => 'ads#delete') then the trace in webrick console shows GET request: "Started GET "/ads/56/delete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-17 23:14:37 -0500 Processing by AdsController#delete as HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"56"}"   [And it all works] I'm not insisting of course on that way of doing things, just trying to understand.